# Tcl/Expect: Can't set variable value correctly

Tags: expect, tcl

I'm trying to get IPSec tunnel details from the router. After that fetch lines with IP addresses.

So, I have follow code:

```
send "show tunnel ipsec remote 10.10.10.10\r"
expect "local"
send "\r"

set outcome $expect_out(buffer)

set records [split $outcome "\n"]

foreach rec $records {
if {[regexp {\*.*$} $rec tunnel_name]} {
regsub -all "\r" $tunnel_name "" tunnel_name
regsub -all " " $tunnel_name "" tunnel_name
set NodeBInfo "Tunnel:\t $tunnel_name"

set command "show tunnel ipsec name $tunnel_name detail | include \"Remote IP\""
send "$command\r"
expect "local"
set outcome1 $expect_out(buffer)
set records1 [split $outcome1 "\n"]     
foreach rec1 $records1 {
if {[regexp {Remote IP :.*$} $rec1 remote_ip]} {
regsub -all "\r" $remote_ip "" remote_ip
append NodeBInfo "\t$remote_ip"
}
}
unset outcome1
unset command

set command "show tunnel ipsec name $tunnel_name detail | include \"IRAC IP\""
send "$command\r"
expect "local"
set outcome2 $expect_out(buffer)
set records2 [split $outcome2 "\n"]     
foreach rec2 $records2 {
if {[regexp {IRAC IP:.*$} $rec2 remote_ip2]} {
regsub -all "\r" $remote_ip "" remote_ip2
append NodeBInfo "\t$remote_ip2"
}
}
unset outcome2
unset command

puts "NodeBInfo $NodeBInfo\r"
}
}
```

I expected following value of NodeBInfo variable:

```
NodeBInfo Tunnel:         *ran_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4049 Remote IP : 10.10.10.10  Local IP    : 20.20.20.20   IRAC IP: 40.40.40.40 / 255.255.255.0
```

But I got only:

```
NodeBInfo Tunnel:         *ran_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4049
```

Full output of script:

```
[local]Router#show tunnel ipsec remote 10.10.10.10


::::: Tunnel : *ran_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4049
   Key       : -
   Remote IP : 10.10.10.10  Local IP    : 20.20.20.20
   Tnl Type  : IPsec       ASP Slot/Id : 6/1
   State     : Up          Bound to    : ipsec_traffic_ran_mb@iub_seg
   Circuit ID: 12479       Internal Hdl: 255/32:511:63:31/0/2/12479

::::: Tunnel : *oam_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4bca
   Key       : -
   Remote IP : 10.10.10.10  Local IP    : 30.30.30.30
   Tnl Type  : IPsec       ASP Slot/Id : 6/1
   State     : Up          Bound to    : ipsec_traffic_mb@om_seg
   Circuit ID: 15340       Internal Hdl: 255/32:511:63:31/0/2/15340
[local]Router#
[local]Router#show tunnel ipsec name *ran_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4049 detail | include "Remote IP"
   Remote IP : 10.10.10.10  Local IP    : 20.20.20.20
[local]Router#NodeBInfo Tunnel:         *ran_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4049
show tunnel ipsec name *ran_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4049 detail | include "IRAC IP"
IRAC IP: 40.40.40.40 / 255.255.255.0
[local]Router#show tunnel ipsec name *oam_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4bca detail | include "Remote IP"
   Remote IP : 10.10.10.10  Local IP    : 30.30.30.30
[local]Router#NodeBInfo Tunnel:         *oam_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4bca
show tunnel ipsec name *oam_tunnel-10.10.10.10-4bca detail | include "IRAC IP"
IRAC IP: 50.50.50.50 / 255.255.255.0
[local]Router#
[local]Router#exit
```